# jqueryUI datepicker and allowing non-dates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

How would I use the jqueryUI "datepicker" if I want my input field to allow non-dates (or invalid dates)?

I have a server-side script which can handle a normal date as input, or an asterisk to mean "latest date available" (amongst a few other special codes).
It would be nice to have a popup datepicker in my HTML form, but only when needed.
How can I use the jqueryUI datepicker to choose a specific date (for example, by clicking on a datepicker icon), while also allowing the user to enter one of our special codes as a "fake date"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`constrainInput`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-constrainInput) option to allow all characters to be entered into the `input`:

```
$("#someElem").datepicker({
    constrainInput: false   
});
```

See this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/frw8j/4/). The first `input` will allow any characters to be typed. The second `input` will only allow the defaults allowed by the `datepicker` widget (which I think is just numbers and the `/` character).

Comment: The developers, they think of everything! Thanks.  (I'm still feeling the glow of coming home after jqCon Boston and finding out about the power of jQUI)

Comment: I'm using this in combination with http://www.datejs.com - it's a great combination for users.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to my recollection that when I've used jQueryUI datepicker the datepicker fills in the value into a text field, but the user can still just close out the picker and type into the text field directly. Give it a try?

Comment: I don't think the jQueryUI will allow you to type special characters like `*`